# How to understand the += in a JavaScript For loop when using it with the innerHTML property?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Just trying to get a better understanding of a JavaScript For loop. I know what the output will be, which is `0-9`:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i + "<br>";
}
```

But what does `innerHTML += i` mean in my script? More specifically, what does the `+=` do, and what does it mean?

Comment: Please **search thoroughly** before posting. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Can you post the link to the exact same question I asked?

Comment: There's not one but **two** linked above.

Comment: OK, I see it, thanks!

Comment: Is this a shorthand `innerHTML += i`? If so, how do you display the longer version?

Comment: No, it's shorthand for `innerHTML = innerHTML + i + "<br>";` As the linked questions' answers say, `a += b` is `a = a + b`.

Comment: I know what the linked answer says. I was asking because I wasn't sure if the `innerHTML += i` meant the same as the linked answer. I thought that's what Stackoverflow was for? But you've cleared it up for me!

Comment: Better save data into variable and then assign it to innerHTML, because each time you will trigger DOM to update.

Answer (score 0):

It means "add to the current value".

The example you give, will take the current innerHTML and add 10
`<br>` tags to it.

Comment: and add 10 `{i}</br>`